# Web API Post method not saving data

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple Web API application which can `GET` or `POST` data back to the user.
Data being a simple array of Strings, `["foo", "bar"]`. If I try and `POST` data to the Web API, the data is read successfully into the `POST` method, but upon returning to the Web API with another call, the data previously Posted would not be there anymore.

How do I keep the data on the Server with every `POST`.

This is what is on my server:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    data.Add(value);
    var msg = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, "Added element");
    msg.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri + "/" + (data.Count - 1).ToString());
    return msg;
}
```

Sending a `POST` with `data = John Doe` will add it to a `List<String>` called data, but it won't persist upon returning to the server.

This is how I am calling the server:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(data), // data = "John Doe"
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Essentially, how can I make `"John Doe"` persist on the server when sending a `POST` to it. Making the `List<String> data = ["foo", "bar", "John Doe"]`

Comment: `Data` is a field on your controller.  Your controller is instantiated per request, so the `Data` field is new on every request.  You need to add some kind of persistence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List<String> data =` simply won't work and persist as you would expect cause that list is defined in your API controller and it gets destroyed after every request since on every request you get a new controller instance.

If you really want to persist it then `Cache` the data by using any kind of caching mechanism distributed cache like `Redis` or non-distributed one.